# Python polars Cannot cast 'Object' type

Tags: python-3.x, python-polars, data-wrangling

I try to convert a pl.Object column to pl.Utf8 the ultimate goal woudl be to get the minimum length of characters in this column in polars. However conversion fails for `pl.Object` dtypes.

```
shape: (5, 1)
┌───────────────────────┐
│ date_strings_missings │
│ ---                   │
│ object                │
╞═══════════════════════╡
│ 03.05.1834            │
│ 03.05.1834            │
│ 05.06.2025            │
│                       │
│ 03.05.1834            │
└───────────────────────┘
```

Example code with the error:

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np


N = 100
data = pl.DataFrame(
    data={
        "date_strings_missings": np.random.choice(
            [None, "", "03.04.1998", "03.05.1834", "05.06.2025"], N
        ),
    }
)

print(data.head())

col = "date_strings_missings"

n_char = (
    data[col]
    .drop_nulls()
    .cast(pl.Utf8)
    .set(data[col].str.lengths() == 0, None)
    .drop_nulls()
    .str.n_chars()
    .min()
)
```

Exception message:

```
Exceptions.ComputeError: cannot cast 'Object' type
```

Comment: You need to prevent `pl.Object` from being created in the first place, e.g. `np.random.choice(...).astype(str)`

Comment: I sadly can't I do get data in this format with `None` or `""` entered in date columns

Comment: Oh right. Well the issue is your numpy array has `dtype=object` - if you converted it to a regular python list e.g.`tolist()`, it would load properly as a `str` column. Is your actual data coming from numpy arrays or is this just an example?

Comment: This is just a MRE so that other people would be able to help me. However I read the data from directly from a database, with `pl.read_database`

Comment: Okay, and `pl.read_database` is creating columns of type `pl.Object`? That probably shouldn't be happening.

Comment: @jqurious It does for a UUID...

Comment: @jtlz2 Ah right. Yeah, I don't think there's any UUID support in Polars as of yet. https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7175